# Let me Ask Jon Skeet for you (LMAJSFY)

Tags: app, website, search

[image: Let me Ask Jon Skeet for you]

[Let me Ask Jon Skeet for you (LMAJSFY)](http://lmajsfy.com/)

For all those people who find it more convenient to bother you with their question rather than [Ask Jon Skeet](http://www.askjonskeet.com/) for themselves.

Enter your search term and click the search button. You will be given a link to an animation, that will show a search being made prior to diverting to the Ask Jon Skeet search engine to see the results.

Inspired by Let Me Google That For you LMGTFY.

[Let me Ask Jon Skeet for you (LMAJSFY)](http://lmajsfy.com/)

Comment: I find the text *click a button* disturbing, there is only one button. I think it should be *click the **search** button*.